# $PATH environment variable does not seem to be recognized

Tags: shell, zsh, path, which

I've made a fresh install of Debian Wheezy, and installed zsh to it. Few days after, I've done a vanilla installation of TeX Live 2014, so I added the necessary binary paths to my $PATH. Now I started writing little scripts so I would like to put them somewhere easily accessible, that is `~/bin`.

My path looks like this:

```
~/bin:/opt/texbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

Now, if I wanted to run something from TeX Live, it's easy:

```
% which pdflatex
/opt/texbin/pdflatex
```

No problem. But when I try running something from `~/bin`, ...

```
% which hello_world
hello_world not found
```

So I double-checked:

```
% ls -l ~/bin
total 18
-rwxr-xr-x 1 bozbalci bozbalci 5382 Sep  8 00:28 hello_world
```

And it shows that hello_world is doing fine in `~/bin` with its execution permissions set. I've tried `rehash`, but it didn't work. Help?

Comment: Do you have a tilde in the value of `PATH`, or in the command that sets `PATH`? You can write `PATH=~/bin:/opt/texbin/…` in a shell script, because the tilde is expanded. But if you run `echo $PATH`, it should show `/home/theconjuring/bin:/opt/texbin:…`. Where are you setting `PATH`?

Comment: Changing `~/bin` to `/home/bozbalci/bin` solves the issue, thanks @Gilles!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a shell command like

```
PATH=~/bin:/opt/texbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

the tilde is expanded to your home directory when the shell command is executed. Thus the resulting value of `PATH` is something like 
`/home/theconjuring/bin:/opt/texbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`.

Make sure that the tilde isn't within quotes (<strike>`PATH="~/bin:…"`</strike>), otherwise it stands for itself. To prepend a directory to the current value of `PATH`, you can use

```
PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

In general, in shells other than zsh, `$PATH` outside double quotes [breaks when the value contains spaces or other special characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters), but in an assignment, it's safe. With `export`, however, you need to write `export PATH=~/bin:"$PATH"` (though you don't need `export` with `PATH` since it's already in the environemnt). In zsh, you don't need double quotes except when the variable may be empty, but if you set `PATH` in `.profile`, it's processed by `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash`.

If you're setting `PATH` in `~/.pam_environment`, however, you can't use `~` or `$HOME` to stand for your home directory. This file is not parsed by a shell, it's a simple list of `NAME=value` lines. So you need to write the paths in full.

Comment: With `zsh`, you can also prepend an element to `$PATH` with `path[1,0]=~/bin`

Answer (score 0):

Update: bash *will* expand ~ in your PATH var. But beware, Python will not. I discovered this the hard way.

```bash
$ export PATH="~/foo:$PATH"
$ type -a foo.sh
foo.sh is /home/myles/foo/foo.sh
```

```py
Python 3.9.11 (main, Sep  2 2022, 07:10:47)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.6.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: shutil.which('foo.sh')
None
```

Comment: The tilde really shouldn't get expanded in the shell if quoted (as the other answer says). Can you check what you get with e.g. `bash -c 'FOO="~/foo"; echo "$FOO"'` and are you sure you didn't actually do that without the quotes, possibly in an earlier command?

Comment: The fact that Python (or whatever other scripting language) does not do its own tilde expansion is not really directly relevant to the current question, where the user is clearly working from the shell's command prompt.

Comment: @ilkkachu As you can see, bash *will* expand a literla tilde when it searches your path Should it? Debatable I guess. But if bash (being the defacto reference) does it, then it would be nice if everyone else did too.
`
$ bash -c 'FOO="~/foo"; echo "$FOO"'
~/foo
$ mkdir ~/foo
$ touch ~/foo/bar
$ chmod +x ~/foo/bar
$ bash -c 'PATH="~/foo"; echo $(which bar)'
/home/epramyl/foo/bar
$ bash -c 'PATH="~/foo"; echo $(which bar); echo $PATH'
/home/mylesp/foo/bar
~/foo
`

Comment: @MylesPrather, yep, looks like you're right, Bash does expand the tilde from `PATH` too. None of the other shells I tried do, though (zsh, Dash, ksh, Busybox). Based on the prompt in the original question, they're probably using zsh (or (t)csh), so what Bash does might not really help them. Leaving the tilde unquoted in the assignment to let it expand before the assignment to `PATH` would make it work with any shell.