# Is it secure to use the following kinds of pathnames in `$PATH`?

Tags: security, environment-variables, filenames, path

Is using the following kinds of pathnames in `$PATH` a secure and good practice:

- empty pathname.

  findutils manual says  it is insecure if `$PATH` contains an empty pathname, and I wonder why?

  Is an empty pathname an absolute or relative pathname?
- pathnames containing tilde or filename expansions.

  Can a user of `$PATH` always understand and perform tilde or filename expansions in `$PATH` like shell?

  If I set the value of `PATH` in a shell startup script such as `~/.profile`, does it matter at all, given that a shell executes the startup file?

  I found one related to tilde expansion https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154290/674
- current working directory. See [Is it safe to add . to my PATH? How come?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65700/is-it-safe-to-add-to-my-path-how-come)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is an empty element in `PATH` this refers to `'.'` and can be seen as insecure.

If the dot or empty element at the end of the `PATH`, this is not highly insecure, since it would only hit if someone places a binary in a directory that uses a misspelled system binary name.

For `CDPATH` it is the other way round: it you do not have the dot or empty element, `cd` will not find subdirectories in the current directory.

The tilde inside a `PATH` string is not understood. This is why the POSIX standard requires to expand tilde sequences after a colon in the command line when a shell macro is assigned.

Regarding the text you added to your question after I answered: these tilde characters are expanded before the command is executed.

Comment: Related to the first point: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65700/is-it-safe-to-add-to-my-path-how-come

Comment: Thanks. "If there is an empty element in PATH this refers to '.'" Does this happen only in $PATH or everywhere?

Comment: `.` is insecure no matter where in `PATH` it appears. People make typos all the time. The classic example is a malicious executable in `/tmp` called `sl`.

Comment: "these tilde characters are expanded before the command is executed." So does it matter whether I use tilde or filename expansions in `$PATH`?

Comment: @Reid mine is `grpe`

Comment: I have some question understanding "The tilde inside a PATH string is not understood. This is why the POSIX standard requires to expand tilde sequences after a colon in the command line when a shell macro is assigned." https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/448521/what-separators-does-the-lexer-of-bash-use-to-break-a-command-into-words

Answer (score 2):

Just so others know if they hit this with google.

If you put `.` in your path and an attacker creates a file called `ls`  in your current working directory that may get executed if it comes up before /bin/ls. That fake ls could be a shell script with `rm -rf` in it, if `.` came up in the path first you may unknowingly run that ls when you issue the command and destroy your files.