# What separators does the lexer of bash use to break a command into words?

Tags: bash

From bash manual, about tilde expansion:

> If **a word** begins with an unquoted tilde character (‘~’), all of the characters up to the first
>   unquoted slash (or all characters, if there is no unquoted slash) are considered a tilde-prefix .

I was wondering why `~` is recognized as  tilde-prefix in

```
$ mypath=/program_files:~/home/t
$ echo $mypath
/program_files:/home/t/home/t
```

What words is `mypath=/program_files:~/home/t` splitted into by the lexer of bash? Is `~/home/t` recognized exactly as a word?

What word separators does the lexer of bash use to break a command into words? Are `:` and `=`  word separators? Are they also words?

Thanks.

This is originated from that I can't understand https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/448469/674

> The tilde inside a PATH string is not understood. This is why the POSIX standard requires to expand tilde sequences after a colon in the command line when a shell macro is assigned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn’t the result of word splitting (more accurately, token splitting), it’s the result of [tilde expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html#Tilde-Expansion) in variable assignments:

> Each variable assignment is checked for unquoted tilde-prefixes immediately following a ‘:’ or the first ‘=’. In these cases, tilde expansion is also performed.

When it splits a command into tokens, the word separators bash uses are its [metacharacters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Definitions.html#Definitions):

> A character that, when unquoted, separates words. A metacharacter is a space, tab, newline, or one of the following characters: ‘|’, ‘&’, ‘;’, ‘(’, ‘)’, ‘<’, or ‘>’.

```
mypath=/program_files:~/home/t
```

is a single token from bash’s perspective.

Comment: Thanks. What words i.e. tokens is `mypath=/program_files:~/home/t` split into?

Comment: Are `=`  and `:`  not metacharacters? What are they?

Comment: Also are `=` and `:` "words" in bash's definition?

Comment: @Tim The whole `mypath=/program_files:~/home/t` is a single token. It is processed as a simple command.

Comment: ‘=’ and ‘:’ are regular characters. ‘=’ acquires special meaning in the context of [shell parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html#Shell-Parameters); as Kusalananda says its presence causes the token to be treated as an assignment. ‘:’ only has special meaning for certain operations, including tilde expansion.

Comment: Thanks. (1) After token splitting, are metacharacters themselves also tokens? (2) some metacharacter can have different meanings, e.g. `<` can be redirection operator, or comparions operator between two numbers.  `&`, `(` and `)` also can have different meanings.  So does  a metacharactor with any of the meanings server as token separator?

Comment: I suspect they are indeed tokens themselves, because as you say they carry meaning. `ps aux|less` and `ps aux | less` are equivalent: `|` doesn’t lose its piping effect when it’s the only separator between words.

Answer (score 3):

The tilde is expanded in the assignment to `PATH` because it is a variable assignment and the tilde comes just after an unquoted colon (in your example).

> A "tilde-prefix" consists of an unquoted `<tilde>` character at the beginning of a word, followed by all of the characters preceding the first unquoted `<slash>` in the word, or all the characters in the word if there is no `<slash>`. In an assignment (see XBD Variable Assignment), multiple tilde-prefixes can be used: at the beginning of the word (that is, following the `<equals-sign>` of the assignment), **following any unquoted `<colon>`**, or both.

(from [the POSIX text on tilde expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01))

The `bash` manual puts it like

> Each variable assignment is checked for unquoted tilde-prefixes
>          immediately following a `:` or the first `=`.  In these cases, tilde
>          expansion is also performed.  Consequently, one may use filenames with
>          tildes in assignments to `PATH`, `MAILPATH`, and `CDPATH`, and the shell
>          assigns the expanded value.

This means that assigning the unquoted string `/program_files:~/home/t` to `PATH` will expand the tilde within, and that `$PATH` will be the string with the tilde expanded.

Placing a literal tilde in `PATH`, for example by quoting the string, will cause pathname resolution of commands to fail for that directory (unless there is a directory in the current working directory with that literal name).

`bash` when not in POSIX mode, will still expand these tildes in `PATH` when looking for commands.

---

When the shell scans the line

```
mypath=/program_files:~/home/t
```

it is returned to the parser as a single token.  It will be processed as a simple command.

A simple command, when recognised as an assignment, undergoes, among other things, tilde expansion. While doing the tilde expansion on the right hand side of the `=`, the shell will expand the tilde in the string to the home directory of the current user, because it occurs just after a colon.

See also [the POSIX text on simple commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01).

Comment: I think the comment about tilde not "being understood" in `PATH` refers to a literal tilde in the `PATH` (i.e. `PATH='~/bin'`). Though Bash does seem to interpret the tilde from inside `PATH`, too, but that's not directly the same as being able to expand it on assignment.

Comment: @ilkkachu I believe that you are correct, I will patch it up by removing that quote from my answer and then write it up properly in the morning, after sleep. Thanks!