# Why is unquoted $PATH containing whitespaces safe in an assignment?

Tags: bash, assignment

What does the following from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154290/674 mean?

> In general, in shells other than zsh, $PATH outside double quotes breaks when the value contains spaces or other special characters, but **in an assignment, it's safe**

Could you give some example? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in simple assignments (e.g. `a=$b`) are by definition (i.e., POSIX specification), not usually necessary to quote -- in most cases, anyway. That is because in these assignments, the "string-splitting" and "globbing" (i.e., white-space and wildcards like `*`) are not expanded.

In other cases, other than assignments, the variable (`echo $b`) *is* expanded -- including whitespaces (string-splitting) -- and hence should be quoted (`echo "$b"`), to prevent problems, in case it contains whitespace. E.g., consider if I'm not using `echo` as an example, but instead another command: `cmd $b` is going to receive multiple args if there are spaces in `$b`, but `cmd "$b"` will receive one argument, even if it has spaces.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958681/quoting-vs-not-quoting-the-variable-on-the-rhs-of-a-variable-assignment